# Convert the date format to dd-mm-yyyy for Curdate() in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I m trying to select the date between today and tomorrow.. and I have to convert the date format from yyyy-mm-dd to dd-mm-yyyy how can I do it . Here is the query

```
select * from abc 
 where mass_date IN(((DATE_FORMAT(curdate(),'%d-%m-%Y')),(DATE_FORMAT(curdate() + interval 1 day,'%d-%m-%Y')))  order by mass_date asc
```

Comment: [For the 1024 time – DateTime has no format!](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/12/19/for-the-1024-time-datetime-has-no-format/) If the data type of `mass_date` is a [date/time data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html#:~:text=MySQL%20retrieves%20and%20displays%20DATETIME,both%20date%20and%20time%20parts.), than `date_format` is irrelevant in the `where` clause. If it's a string data type, then you have bigger problems.

Comment: Fix your data so `mass-date` is a `date`, not a string.